# Find the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix via the power method

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Find the smallest eigenvalue of the following matrix via the power method.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0\\
-1 &  2 & -1\\
 0 & -1 &  2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Accurate up to $3$ decimal places

Comment: How much do you pay, boss?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?